# Symfony 2.5 Enum field

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, enums

I want use Symfony2.5 and Doctrine with my existing database. When I'm usgin command: 
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force MyBundle xml

I get an error:
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force MyBundle xml

I found solution: write into file app/config/config.yml this thing

mapping_types:
              enum: string

But It doesn't work and I'm getting next error:
 Property "parent" in "Message" was already declared, but it must be declare
  d only once . How can I solve it?

Comment: Almost solved, but is there in Doctrine possibility to create Entity for table where one field has three parent fields from other tables?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.

It should with different name.

Comment: Can you please explain this? In my table from field parent_id I have three foreign keys to three different tables and their fields id. But when I left just one foreign key it started working. But I need three keys. How can I do it in Doctrine?

Comment: Sorry I miss interpret your comment. I read it as for one table with three foreign key. I don't know about one column with multiple foreign key. And as I know any dbms not allow this type of relationship. I say sorry again for this without interpreting your query properly I post answer.